# Move_base stuck at Sim period

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm a begginer with ros

I'm trying to use move_base to control my robot but i don't know why my move_base stuck at Sim period is set to 0.20 and cant receive odom like in this https://imgur.com/E7uYihx

This is my screen while launching move_base https://imgur.com/BWQkXLA

This is my tf tree https://imgur.com/NZ7zJfw

This is my main launch file

```
 <launch>
  <node pkg="robot" type="lidar_tf.py" name="lidar_tf" output="screen"/>
  <node pkg="robot" type="diff_tf.py" name="diff_tf" output="screen"/>
  <node name="rplidarNode"          pkg="rplidar_ros"  type="rplidarNode" output="screen">
  <param name="serial_port"         type="string" value="/dev/ttyUSB0"/>  
  <param name="serial_baudrate"     type="int"    value="115200"/>
  <param name="frame_id"            type="string" value="laser"/>
  <param name="inverted"            type="bool"   value="false"/>
  <param name="angle_compensate"    type="bool"   value="true"/>
 </node>
<include file="$(find robot)/launch/gmapping.launch"/>
</launch>
```

This is my navigation launch file

```
<launch>
  <!-- Name of the map to use (without path nor extension) and initial position -->
  <arg name="map_file"       default=" $(find robot)/map/mymap.yaml"/> <!-- psu -->
  <arg name="initial_pose_x" default="20.925"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_y" default="11.925"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_a" default="0.0"/>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>

<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)">
   
  </node>


<include file="$(find robot)/launch/amcl.launch.xml">
    <arg name="scan_topic" value="scan"/>
    <arg name="use_map_topic" value="true"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_a" value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
  </include>
  <!--  ************** Navigation  ***************  -->
  <include file="$(find robot)/launch/move_base.launch.xml"/>
 <!--
 <node pkg="robot" type="navigation.py" name="navigation" output="screen">
    <rosparam param="xHome">2.77388</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="YHome">-2.25284</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="xDestination">-51.225</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="yDestination">-51.225</rosparam>
 </node>
-->

</launch>\
```

This is my move_base

```
<launch>
  <arg name="odom_frame_id"   default="odom"/>
  <arg name="base_frame_id"   default="base_link"/>
  <arg name="global_frame_id" default="map"/>
  <arg name="odom_topic" default="odom" />
  <arg name="laser_topic" default="scan" />
 
  

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find robot)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />   
    <rosparam file="$(find robot)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />   
    <rosparam file="$(find robot)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot)/param/dwa_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot)/param/global_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot)/param/navfn_global_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <param name="global_costmap/global_frame" value="$(arg global_frame_id)"/>
    <param name="global_costmap/robot_base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame_id)"/>
    <param name="local_costmap/global_frame" value="$(arg odom_frame_id)"/>
    <param name="local_costmap/robot_base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame_id)"/>
    <param name="DWAPlannerROS/global_frame_id" value="$(arg odom_frame_id)"/>
    <remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="$(arg laser_topic)"/>
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS" />

  </node>
</launch>
```

This is my amcl

```
    <launch>
  <arg name="use_map_topic"   default="false"/>
  <arg name="scan_topic"      default="scan"/> 
  <arg name="initial_pose_x"  default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_y"  default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_a"  default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="odom_frame_id"   default="odom"/>
  <arg name="base_frame_id"   default="base_link"/>
  <arg name="global_frame_id" default="map"/>

  <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl">
    <param name="use_map_topic"             value="$(arg use_map_topic)"/>
    <!-- Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->
    <param name="odom_model_type"           value="diff-corrected"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha5"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="gui_publish_rate"          value="10.0"/>
    <param name="laser_max_beams"             value="60"/>
    <param name="laser_max_range"           value="12.0"/>
    <param name="min_particles"             value="500"/>
    <param name="max_particles"             value="2000"/>
    <param name="kld_err"                   value="0.05"/>
    <param name="kld_z"                     value="0.99"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha1"               value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha2"               value="0.2"/>
    <!-- translation std dev, m -->
    <param name="odom_alpha3"               value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha4"               value="0.2"/>
    <param name="laser_z_hit"               value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_z_short"             value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_max"               value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_rand"              value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_sigma_hit"           value="0.2"/>
    <param name="laser_lambda_short"        value="0.1"/>
    <param name="laser_model_type"          value="likelihood_field"/>
    <!-- <param name="laser_model_type" value="beam"/> -->
    <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
    <param name="update_min_d"              value="0.25"/>
    <param name="update_min_a"              value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id"             value="$(arg odom_frame_id)"/> 
    <param name="base_frame_id"             value="$(arg base_frame_id)"/> 
    <param name="global_frame_id"           value="$(arg global_frame_id)"/>
    <param name="resample_interval"         value="1"/>
    <!-- Increase tolerance because the computer can get quite busy -->
    <param name="transform_tolerance"       value="1.0"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_slow"       value="0.0"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_fast"       value="0.0"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_x"            value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_y"            value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_a"            value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
    <remap from="scan"                      to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

this is gmapping.launch

```
<launch>
  <arg name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" default="scanmatcher_frame"/>
  <arg name="base_frame" default="base_link"/>
  <arg name="odom_frame" default="odom"/>
  <arg name="pub_map_odom_transform" default="true"/>
  <arg name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" default="5"/>
  <arg name="scan_topic" default="scan"/>
  <arg name="map_size" default="2048"/>


 <node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping" output="screen">
    
    <!-- Frame names -->
    <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
    <param name="base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame)" />
    <param name="odom_frame" value="$(arg odom_frame)" />
    
    <!-- Tf use -->
    <param name="use_tf_scan_transformation" value="true"/>
    <param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="false"/>
    <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="$(arg pub_map_odom_transform)"/>
    <param name="pub_map_scanmatch_transform" value="false"/>
    
    <!-- Map size / start point -->
    <param name="map_resolution" value="0.050"/>
    <param name="map_size" value="$(arg map_size)"/>
    <param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
    <param name="map_multi_res_levels" value="2" />
    
    <!-- Map update parameters -->
    <param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
    <param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.9" />    
    <param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.4"/>
    <param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />
    <param name="laser_z_min_value" value = "-1.0" />
    <param name="laser_z_max_value" value = "1.0" />
    
    <!-- Advertising config --> 
    <param name="advertise_map_service" value="true"/>
    
    <param name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" value="$(arg scan_subscriber_queue_size)"/>
    <param name="scan_topic" value="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
    
    <!-- Debug parameters -->
    <!--
      <param name="output_timing" value="false"/>
      <param name="pub_drawings" value="true"/>
      <param name="pub_debug_output" value="true"/>
    -->
    <param name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" value="$(arg tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name)" />
  </node>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 100" />

<!--
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_odom" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom 100" />
-->
</launch>
```

Thanks you for any help <3

---

Update:

I sill can receive data to odom but nothing happend in move_base...

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367221/move_base-stuck-at-sim-period/) by [hiep127](https://answers.ros.org/users/64783/hiep127/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-12-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-12-15**:
@hiep127 please don't post an *update* as an *answer*. Please update your question instead

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-12-15**:
Also, for any text please don't use images as the text in images can't be copy and pasted. Please see [the support page](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's generally better to post the text of your files/code directly with the `101010` formatting button.  That way it's searchable.  That aside, your tf tree indicates you probably have something setup incorrectly.  The `map` frame is usually the root of the tree and parent of the `odom` frame, which is the parent of `base_link`.  The `map->odom` tf comes from mapping/SLAM, and the `odom->base_link` tf comes from odometry (sensor data).  The [navigation tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials) provide an excellent resource for getting started.  I recommend following along in simulation before trying to apply it to hardware.  If you've done that and are still having problems, please, post all of the launch files/code you are using.  Looking at the node/topic graph with `rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph` may also help.  Finally, ensure that something is publishing odometry with `rostopic echo /odom`.  If you don't see "odom received," it's likely not published or on the wrong topic.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2020-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hiep127](https://answers.ros.org/users/64783/hiep127/) on 2020-12-08**:
Tks for ur advice it my second time using this forum and i still dont know all about its feature yet xD

I will try ur advice and hope it will work :3

thanks again for ur help

**Comment by [hiep127](https://answers.ros.org/users/64783/hiep127/) on 2020-12-09**:
https://imgur.com/NZ7zJfw

I have made tf tree look like this but it still now work :(

i updated the launch file i am using too

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2020-12-09**:
Thanks for the additional info.  As mentioned above, looking at the node graph and echoing the topics will help determine if anything is publishing data on `odom`.  Your tree indicates that `diff_tf` is publishing the `odom`->`base_link` transform.  It appears to be a custom node, so I can't say whether that's correct without the source code--same for `lidar_tf.py` and `navigation.py`.  On a side note, I recommend [`static_transform_publisher` nodes](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher) for generating constant transforms instead if that's what your `lidar_tf` node is doing.  I don't see anything that's clearly publishing odometry, though.

Your tree also indicates a `hector_mapping` node, but I don't see that in your launch files.  You also reference a `gmapping` launch file and use a `map_server` node.  I would step back from navigation and be sure your localization setup working first, including odometry.  What is your setup as you see it?

**Comment by [hiep127](https://answers.ros.org/users/64783/hiep127/) on 2020-12-09**:
sorry for the missing information

diff_tf is a node povided by http://wiki.ros.org/differential_drive which can be used to get odometry from differential robot and hector_mapping is a SLAM (http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam) so i don't think they are the problem.....

Also for localization  i have tried run the robot by hand with teleop_twist_keyboard and it create an accurate map in rviz so that i  don't think it's a problem too so i forget to post it

**Comment by [hiep127](https://answers.ros.org/users/64783/hiep127/) on 2020-12-09**:
this is lidar_tf

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
    import roslib
    
    
    import rospy
    import tf
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        rospy.init_node('lidar_tf')
        br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
        rate = rospy.Rate(10.0)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            br.sendTransform((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                             (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
                             rospy.Time.now(),
                             "laser",
                             "base_link")
            rate.sleep()
```

**Comment by [hiep127](https://answers.ros.org/users/64783/hiep127/) on 2020-12-09**:
i also update the gmapping.launch file and i also echo to odom and there are data published to odom but idk why my move_base cant receive it

**Comment by [hiep127](https://answers.ros.org/users/64783/hiep127/) on 2020-12-09**:
Also i have a question to ask

Ask u mentioned be4 the map to odom come from mapping/slam but SLAM also published to /map topic

if i run SLAM so that i can't publish a map to map_server right? @@!

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2020-12-09**:
The `diff_tf` node is old but may be fine, though you should consider the [`diff_drive_controller` package](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller) in the future.  Is it definitely publishing odometry data on the `odom` topic?  Is that topic connected to the correct nodes?

When you teleop your robot, do you get the correct odometry output?

If you're using `hector_slam`, why do you also run `amcl` and a `map_server` node?  Please, describe your work flow and overall setup.

The `lidar_tf.py` code looks fine, but `static_transform_publisher` is a standard node that does the same thing.

EDIT: apparently I missed some of your comments before posting this, so ignore the parts you answered.

**Comment by [hiep127](https://answers.ros.org/users/64783/hiep127/) on 2020-12-09**:
I want to use hector to create a map and then use `amcl` and `move_base` to drive it automatically

So that mean if i want to use `amcl` i need to turn off hector and run a `tf` from map to odom ?

For the odom i post a picture in which i echo to `odom` and seem like it still get data

And yeah after i fix this problem i will start using `static_transform_publisher`

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2020-12-09**:
Yes, you can use `amcl` with `map_server`, or you can use `hector_mapping`.  They both handle localization, so either one works with `move_base`.  Since you chose `amcl`, turn off hector.  The `amcl` node will provide the `map->odom` transform, so no need to publish it yourself.

Since there's data on the `odom` topic, but `move_base` doesn't receive it, there's something wrong with the connection.  `rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph` should show if the connection exists.  Also, I just noticed that `use_sim_time` is set to `true` in your navigation launch file.  That should be `false` for a real robot and could be the reason for no "odom received" message--the clock never starts!

**Comment by [hiep127](https://answers.ros.org/users/64783/hiep127/) on 2020-12-09**:
Oh when i turn off amcl and map_server and sim_time it finally WORK

Thanks u very muchhhhhhhhh

I have stuck with this for about a weeks....

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2020-12-09**:
Great!  Glad I could help.